# Divi Blog Module Plugin and YOAST SEO "Primary Category"

Tags: themes, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am using the Divi Template and have YOAST SEO installed. YOAST SEO has the great feature to assign "Primary Categoy" should a post have more than one category.
Now the Divi Blog Module offers that you can display post meta (which includes the category, author etc). But the moment I activate to display the category it displays all categories and not the YOAST Primary category.

I went to Elegantthemes/DIVI if they have an idea how to solve it but they have apparently no idea.

Does anyone here have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither Divi nor YOAST are able to help. I ended up hardcoding the entire frontpage.